# get value of closest select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to get value of nearest select box when user clicks a link next to it.

It returns undefined in the console

http://jsfiddle.net/vkaCB/

```
<select name="songSelection_amclaughlin" class="songSelection_input">
    <option value="">SELECT ITEM</option>
    <option value="value 1">value 1</option>
    <option value="value 2">value 2</option>
    <option value="value 3">value 3</option>
</select> 

<span class="vote-btns">
    <a href="#" class="button fb grey">Vote</a>
    <a href="#" class="button tw grey">Vote</a>
</span>
```

// js

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("a.button").click(function(event) {
        console.log($(this).closest('select').val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The select is not a parent of the anchors, and `closest()` targets parents only and finds the closest one matching the selector.

```
$(this).closest('span').prev('select').val()
```

What you probably want is to find the closest span, and then the previous select

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {  
    $("a.button").click(function(event) {
     console.log($(this)
       .parents('.vote-btns')
       .prev('select')
       .find('option[selected]').attr('value'));
    });
});
```

or

```
  $(document).ready(function() {  
    $("a.button").click(function(event) {
     console.log($(this)
       .parents('.vote-btns')
       .prev('select')
       .value());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Selecting elements based on the DOM structure is a very brittle strategy - any change to the DOM will cause the code to fail. The control has a name, so why not use that?

```
$('select[name=songSelection_amclaughlin]').val();
```

or without jQuery:

```
document.querySelector('select[name=songSelection_amclaughlin]').value;
```

If necessary, add the class to the selector also. Now the DOM structure can be anything and the select will still be found.